# Shadow glitches in Cycles

Tags: rendering, shadows

When I render my scene in Cycles, I get these really weird glitches (Pictured in image). They happen more and more frequently the less directally my light source is illuminating them. Sorry if this is relatively simple, I am new to blender.

[image: The glitches in question. There is supposed to be a solid, gradient shadow.]

[image: a larger shot of where some glitches are (and where they aren't)]
[image: the most zoomed-out shot of the animation, where the glitches are present but slightly harder to see]
I might add that the render is an animation which both needs both very high (60000m) and fairly low (6m) clipping distance, and these glitches look a bit like what happens in the viewport when I set the clip distance really low. Not sure if this is at all relevant just thought that I might as well add it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried recalculating normals? I often get weird artifacts/shadows when the normals get flipped around.

1. Tab into edit mode with your mesh selected
2. Select all the faces of the mesh with `A`
3. For blender 2.8 `SHIFT + N` brings up the recalculate normals tool. You want to "Recalculate Outside".

Or you can access this via:
Edit Mode > `A` > Mesh menu > Normals > Recalculate Outside

[image]

[https://all3dp.com/2/blender-recalculate-normals-simply-explained/#:~:text=There%20are%20two%20main%20ways,so%20they%20all%20face%20outwards](https://all3dp.com/2/blender-recalculate-normals-simply-explained/#:%7E:text=There%20are%20two%20main%20ways,so%20they%20all%20face%20outwards).

Explanation of normals from [All3DP](https://all3dp.com/2/blender-recalculate-normals-simply-explained/#:%7E:text=There%20are%20two%20main%20ways,so%20they%20all%20face%20outwards.):

> Ever wondered why your Blender model is sometimes plagued by random
> black voids?
>
> The normal of a face describes the direction it’s pointing or facing.
> Usually, in a closed model, all normals should be facing outwards.
>
> However, sometimes when manually manipulating edges and faces in
> Blender, the normals get flipped. It’s not the end of the world, but
> it does make your model look weird. And once you export the model,
> flipped normals can leave behind bad artifacts.
>
> That’s why it’s best to fix these flipped normals. And the good news
> is, they’re super easy to recalculate.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the problem.. The shadows happen in every object, in different places depending on the lighting.

Comment: @UberRix Would you be able to post more screenshots of the whole scene? Thanks in advanced :)

Comment: yup, I added them to the body of the post.

Comment: Could this just be a problem with the Cycles engine? I have found nothing on the internet regarding this problem

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error, I figured out what my problem was. I was using the denoise node, but my sample count was low enough where it had trouble making sense of where light bounced and what objects really looked like. Therefore, all I had to do was increase my sample count, and the artifacts went away.